# Llamar clase a un formulario c#

Tags: c#, wcf

Tengo una duda respecto a mi proyecto. Estoy haciendo una aplicación WCF cliente servidor en Windows Forms. Creé un WCF service library en el cual creo una clase con un método. Después, para el servidor usé la referencia de la clase que creé. Mi problema es que, cuando invoco un método en mi servidor llamando mi clase, no me deja porqué no puede instanciar los métodos.

Clase WCF

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace ArduinoWCF
{
  [ServiceContract]
public class arduino
{
    
    [OperationContract]
    public void control(string mensaje)
    {  ////////FOCP 1
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
        if (mensaje.Contains("1"))
        {

            port.Write("1");
        }

        else if (mensaje.Contains("1"))
        {
            port.Write("2");
        }
        /////FOCO 2
        else if (mensaje.Contains("3"))
        {

            port.Write("3");
        }
        else if (mensaje.Contains("4"))
        {

            port.Write("4");
        }
        ////////FOCO 3
        else if (mensaje.Contains("5"))
        {

            port.Write("5");
        }
        else if (mensaje.Contains("6"))
        {

            port.Write("6");
        }
        /////
    }
  }
}
```

Cabe mencionar que esta clase genera un archivo DLL y ya está añadido al formulario del servidor.

Comment: SerialPort con WCF, mmm eso no lo veo posible. Recuerda que los servicio son sin estado si el puerto envia alguna accion el codigo del servicio WCF en el servidor no va a recibirlo. Quizas si aplique si envias algo, pero habria que ver temas de seguridad

Comment: Mencionas que creas una clase con un metodo, pero en el codigo que nos muestras no veo ninguno, solo la clase SerialPort pero eso no es una clase que tu hayas creado, esa es parte del framework de .net

Answer (score 0):

A pesar que no muestras el código de tu clase, lo que quizás este pasando es que a tu clase no le estés dando la decoración necesaria sobre un objeto que necesitas exponer. Toda clase lleva [DataContract] encima de ella y toda propiedad que debas usar lleva [DataMember] encima de el. Después que no te hayas olvidado de colocar que sea public. y WCF tiene 3 estados, PerSession, Single (es como un singleton en servicios web), PerCall, te dejo la doc oficial. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency, y un método no puede instanciarse, si una clase.